# File Share Deletion (Azure ) failing ,how to fix?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-file-share

I have a piece of code which iterates over file share and delete the file share, while deleting it may contain snapshots ,how do I delete file share as it keeps failing with Error Message like .
**"Unable to delete file share because one or more share snapshots have active leases,**
Note: I could not see any properties letting me know lease ID and even snapshot time is null .Over Portal there is a delete lock at storage account level ,does it restrict the deletion of file shares ?

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
string storageconnectionstring = "Storage Account connection string";
CloudStorageAccount c = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageconnectionstring);
CloudFileClient fileclient= c.CreateCloudFileClient();


foreach(var x in fileclient.ListShares()) {

x.DeleteIfExists(DeleteShareSnapshotsoptions.IncludeSnapshots ,AccessCondition.GenerateEmpty(),
new FileRequestOptions(), new OperationContext())----> This code is failing

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> **"Unable to delete file share because one or more share snapshots have active leases,**

The error shows in your **`File-share`** has some active snapshots so that cannot be deleted.

I tried in my environment with piece of code to delete the snapshots.

You can use the **`azure.storage.files.share`**package to able to delete the snapshots.

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Files.Shares;

namespace fileshare
{
    class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<Account name>;AccountKey=<Account key >==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            var shareName = "share1";
            var snapshot = "2022-10-22T10:23:02.0000000Z";
            ShareServiceClient shareserviceclient = new ShareServiceClient(connectionString);
            ShareClient shareClient = shareserviceclient.GetShareClient(shareName).WithSnapshot(snapshot);
            shareClient.Delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]